# Throw and Catch Custom Exception

Tags: java, file, exception, fileopendialog

I have a method to load a customer file by choosing it from the File Open Dialog Box and it works, except for when I click the Cancel button. It still loads the selected file even if I press the Cancel button. I want to load a Custom Exception if I click the Cancel Button. Any help on how to implement the Custom Exception in my method please? Thanks

```
 private void loadCustomerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   Customer customerfile = null;
   try {

     final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("Customers/");
     int chooserOption = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
     chooserOption = JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION;

     File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
     ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
       new FileInputStream(file)
     );

     customerfile = (Customer) in .readObject();

     custnameTF.setText(customerfile.getPersonName());
     custsurnameTF.setText(customerfile.getPersonSurname());
     custidTF.setText(customerfile.getPersonID());
     custpassidTF.setText(customerfile.getPassaportID());
     customertellTF.setText(customerfile.getPersonTel());
     customermobTF.setText(customerfile.getPersonMob());
     consnameTF.setText(customerfile.getConsultantname());
     conssurnameTF.setText(customerfile.getConsultantsurname());
     considTF.setText(customerfile.getConsulid());

     in .close();

   } catch (IOException ex) {
     System.out.println("Error Loading File" + ex.getMessage());
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
     System.out.println("Error Loading Class");
   } finally {
     System.out.println("Customer Loaded");
   }

 }
```

Comment: Please don't use Javascript stack snippets for Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your method declaration to trow your Exception:

```
private void loadCustomerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    throws CustomException {
```

You are giving always `APPROVE_OPTION` to chooserOption:

```
 chooserOption = JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION;
```

You must make dialog button listener to modify this variable and add a condition:

```
if (chooserOption == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    // load file
} else {
    throw new CustomException("ERROR MESSAGE");
}
```

And your `CustomException` Class must look like:

```
class CustomExceptionextends Exception {
    public CustomException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, now I understand the concept but when I try to insert my Custom Exception its saying "constructor CancelExcpetion in class CancelExcpetion cannot be applied to given types; required String"

Comment: totally true, please check my update. you must throw an eception that matches with given constructor: `throw new CustomException("ERROR MESSAGE");` !!!!

Comment: Amazing Jordi! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're doing an assignment instead of a test on the result of the chooser.

Instead of

```
chooserOption = JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION;
```

you should have

```
if (chooserOption == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    // handle open file
} else {
    throw new CancelException();
}
```

**EDIT**

In response to the comment, exceptions should extend either Exception (for checked exceptions), RuntimeException (for unchecked exceptions) or a descendent of one of those classes.  The only difference at this level is that you don't need to declare unchecked exceptions in the `throws` of the method signature.  Your exception will look something like this

```
public class CancelException extends Exception {

    public CancelException() {
    }

    public CancelException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

One other comment - exceptions should be used for exceptional circumstances.  It's generally considered bad practice to use them to implement logic - do you actually need to use an exception?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, now I understand the concept but when I try to insert my Custom Exception its saying "constructor CancelExcpetion in class CancelExcpetion cannot be applied to given types; required String"

Answer (score 1):

You should not assign anyting to `chooserOption`. You should use a return value of `JFileChooser.showOpenDialog()`, it holds info about the result of dialog showing.
Example:

```
int chooserOption = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if (chooserOption == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
   // throw your exception (or do some other actions) here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not using the chooserOption, once it has selected value, just add a if condition that check for chooserOption value, if selected, executed else throw your exception